# What do the null-related property attributes in Xcode do?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

With Xcode 6.3 I noticed some property attributes, namely:

- `nonnull`
- `null_resettable`
- `nullable`

Could someone explain what they do when applied?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Apple has added two new type annotations:

- A`__nullable` pointer may have a `nil` value,
- while a `__nonnull` cannot have a `nil` value

As you should know in Swift you can use Ottionals, but in Objective-C you cannot. Those attributes let you create Objective-C code which is more understandable by Swift and compiler warn you when you break the rule, for example:

```objectivec
@property (copy, nullable) NSString *name;
@property (copy, nonnull) NSArray *allItems;
```

This will be 'translated' in swift to:

```swift
var name: String?
var allItems: [AnyObject]!
```

This is taken from [NSHipster](https://nshipster.com/swift-1.2/):

> `nonnull`: Indicates that the pointer should/will never be `nil`. Pointers
> annotated with `nonnull` are imported into Swift as their non-optional
> base value (i.e., `NSData`).
>
> `nullable`: Indicates that the pointer can be nil in general practice.
> Imported into Swift as an optional value (`NSURL?`).
>
> `null_unspecified`: Continues the current functionality of
> importing into Swift as an implicitly unwrapped optional, ideally to
> be used during this annotation process only.
>
> `null_resettable`:
> Indicates that while a property will always have a value, it can be
> reset by assigning nil. Properties with a non-nil default value can be
> annotated this way, like tintColor. Imported into Swift as a
> (relatively safe) implicitly unwrapped optional. Document accordingly!

Comment: So basically; these attributes are only used in context with Swift right?

Comment: Mainly yes, but you will receive compiler warnings if you try to assign null to property marked as nonnull in Objective-C as well.