# For help '@property (nonnull)' what it is?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

`@property (nonnull)` . Does `nonnull` added in iOS8.3 and what can it do?

Comment: Why do you think do new Xcode versions come with release notes? They come with release notes so that people read them instead of asking questions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will pay attention next time. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes , it is added in XCode 6.3

Got this information from [here (nshipster)](http://nshipster.com/swift-1.2/)

> nonnull: Indicates that the pointer should/will never be nil.
>   Pointers annotated with nonnull are imported into Swift as their
>   non-optional base value (i.e., NSData).

There are also other two similar properties

- null_resettable

> Indicates that while a property will always have a value, it can be
>   reset by assigning nil. Properties with a non-nil default value can be
>   annotated this way, like tintColor. Imported into Swift as a
>   (relatively safe) implicitly unwrapped optional.

- nullable

> Indicates that the pointer can be nil in general practice. Imported
>   into Swift as an optional value

- null_unspecified

> Continues the current functionality of importing into Swift as an
>   implicitly unwrapped optional, ideally to be used during this
>   annotation process only.

You can have a look at  [What do the null-related property attributes in XCode do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532640/what-do-the-null-related-property-attributes-in-xcode-do)

Comment: You are the greatest. It's very userful.  :)